# How many people are on Christianity Stack Exchange because of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

As a programmer and Jesus-lover, I'm very curious what portion of people made it to Christianity StackExchange because of programming.

Please also let me know how you got here if it wasn't through Stack Overflow.

Thanks!

Comment: Look up everyone’s profile and work the numbers.

Comment: Google brought me here

Comment: Not a programmer but can't remember how I got to Stack Exchange. I was on SE-Biblical Hermeneutics and SE-EL&U (English Language and Usage) first, before SE-C.

Comment: My first site was [linguistics.se].

Comment: @KenGraham Done :-P https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6909/6520

Comment: @kutschkem So 39% of us are uniquely on **Christianity SE**! However **how many people are on Christianity Stack Exchange because of Stack Overflow** is a more nuanced question.

Comment: @KenGraham I suspect that doesn't include the users who've hidden their profile from the rest of the network.

Answer (score 4):

Not me!  I know zip about computer programming and I'd never heard of Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow.  What brought me here was research into a specific question about Christianity.  My "go to" site for information on the Bible and Christianity did not have the detailed information I needed to complete an assignment and it was my sister who suggested Christianity Exchange.

I was delighted to find such a rich source of research material although I confess it took perseverance on my part to get to grips with the way this site operates.

P.S. This was back in January 2018 and I eventually found an answer to my question on the Mi Yodeya site.

Answer (score 3):

https://data.stackexchange.com/christianity/query/1227984/users-on-stackoverflow-and-christianity

10826 of 27659 (= 39%)  as of 2020-04-17

Comment: Probably the closest percentage mark we can get in the system. However there is a difference between those on **Christianity SE** and not on any other site within the **Stack Overflow** system. There is a nuance to the question asked here. **How many people are on Christianity Stack Exchange because of Stack Overflow?** For example, I joined because of Christianity SE, but I am also one other sites as well. Your percentage marks only those that are uniquely on this site. At least that is how I read the data.

Comment: Best answer so far +1.

Comment: It marks those that are both on StackOverflow and Christianity.SE. If you wanted it a little bit more in the spirit of "joined here because of StackOverflow" then you could exclude those that joined Christianity.SE BEFORE StackOverflow, but I doubt it will be a lot of people. You would also have to take into account the spanish, portuguese and russian StackOverflow sites.  In any case, 61% of Christianity.SE users are not users of (english) StackOverflow.

Comment: Impressive!!! +1

Comment: Does this include the users who've hidden their profile from the rest of the network?

Comment: My profile is hidden from the rest of the network. You can search my user id 3961 and see if that reports that I'm on other SE sites. I am, but that fact should be hidden.

Comment: @3961 I didn't manage to create a query that returned something for your Id. So I guess hidden stuff is also hidden in Data.SE (?)

Comment: @kutschkem Good to know, but a small shortcoming on this query, I'm sure. Not too many hide all their site profiles as I've done.

Comment: It's an estimate, alright, but I don't really expect the true value be very far from what this relatively simple query returns. I don't feel it's that important whether the value is 39% or something like 42%, although in keeping the answer so short I of course feigned more precision than there really is here.

Answer (score 1):

I did. I first encountered Stack Overflow when searching for an answer to a computer-related question and then discovered the other communities, including Christianity.

Answer (score 1):

As a new member of a week or so, I also found my way here via a Google search, and although I work in IT I am not a programmer and don't use the Stack Overflow site.  The question that brought me here was about why Jesus spent 40 days on earth between His resurrection and His ascension.  Glad to have found StackExchange, although it is a strange name considering the content!  It is an excellent concept and wonderful tool for research, it is just taking a bit of time to get to grips with how it works.